# Clear Default App ONLY for specific Intent

Tags: android

I know it is possible to clear all Preferred Activities for my Package using

> getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());

But is it posible only to clear a specific one? For example clear the Intent.CATEGORY_HOME but still keep the default for lets say android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE?

I am talking newer devices HoneyComb and above.

I have tried to change the package name for the Image_Capture Activity but to no effect (makes sense since the User can reset the Preferred Activites per App not per Package, so the clearPackagePreferredActivities works just as that button).

If this is the only possibility to clear the defaults, than I would need to make two apks - one for the Home-App and one for the Photo-App to get the desired effect.

(Note that the photo-app does really nothing but is designed to bar the user from using camera as part of blocking of my Kiosk-App).

Comment: I did not find any way of clearing only one Preferred Activity of two. The simple solution was just to make another very simple app that only got the "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" Preferance (and did nothing more than show a toast that image view was blocked).